# How to add chars to paragraph's end of line

Tags: javascript, html, css

Suppose I have this html:

```
<style>
    p { text-align: justify; margin:0; }
</style>

<p>This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. Last line
<p>This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. Last line 
<!-- more paragraphs -->
```

How to add "-" chars to paragraph's end of line, so become:

This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. Last line ---------------------------------------
This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. Last line -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Amount of "-" character varies between paragraph to complete the last line.
Using background image does not work, as paragraph breaks into lines.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want with javascript?

Comment: javascript acceptable :)

Comment: every paragraph has <p>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out [**this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/godfrzero/QESTF/).

```
<style>
  .someWrapper { width: 500px; }
</style>


<div class="someWrapper">
  <p>
     This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. 
     This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. 
     This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. 
     This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. 
     This is a paragraph. Last line
  </p>
</div>


<script>
  var $someParagraph = $('.someWrapper p'),
      originalHeight = $someParagraph.height();

  while( $someParagraph.height() === originalHeight ) {
    var paraContents = $someParagraph.html();
    $someParagraph.html( paraContents + '-' );
  }

  // You'll end up with one extra character, just use the contents
  // from the beginning of the previous iteration
  $someParagraph.html( paraContents );
</script>
```

We're using the fact that the height of the `<p>` element changes when a new line is added to our advantage, and appending characters until just before that point.

Of course, be careful when using `while` loops like this, depending on your HTML structure, you might find yourself inside an infinite loop.

Answer (score 2):

I think that [@godfrzero posted an excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17783444/5651).

I am going to post a CSS-based solution that is more fragile, but illustrates that it is possible to accomplish this with a background image.

**See Working Demo `>`**
http://jsfiddle.net/QESTF/11/

If you use a background image that is roughly the same height as a line of text, you can align it to the bottom and repeat horizontally.

```
.someWrapper {
  background: #fff url('http://regexpal.com/assets/link.gif') 100% 100% repeat-x;
}
```

Then, you could wrap the contents of the `<p>` with an element that has `display:inline` and set the background color to the same background background as `.someWrapper`.

```
<div class="someWrapper">
  <p><span>This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. {repeat}</span></p>
</div>

.someWrapper p span {
  background: white;
  padding-right: 2pt;
}
```

Again, this is a very brittle approach, but for some scenarios it might be the best option.

Comment: @jessegavin Wow, this is probably the first time I'm seeing an original pure CSS solution to this. This is definitely better in cases where the background is uniform.

Answer (score -1):

Something like that ?

[Follow this text](http://jsfiddle.net/9ZtXf/)

example : Last line ------

you can add property for add content / effect after the element

```
> p:after{clear:both;content:"--------";}
```

[Break last line](http://jsfiddle.net/9ZtXf/1/)

```
> p:after{clear:both;content:"--------";display:block;}
```

example : Last line

'-----

Comment: why is htis getting downvoted? This is best answer imo.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

**HTML**

```
<p>This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. Last line</p>
```

**CSS**

```
p { text-align: justify; margin:0; }
p:after {
    content:"------";
}
```

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZzzXM/